# Using Tika in Python and Regular Expression To Extract Text From PDF

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract specific information from the PDF using Tika in Python. I tried to incorporate regex into the code, but it returns an error. Here is my code:

```
from tika import parser
import re

parsed = parser.from_file("PDF/File.pdf")
desc = re.findall(r'((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)+)\b\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)+:|$)', parsed)

print(desc["content"])
```

The error returned is as follows:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'dict'
```

Is there a solution to fix the error and a way so that the regex can be passed into the code?

Comment: Don't know tika at all, but looking into its documentation shows that `parsed` indeed is a dictionary. I think you want to inspect the PDF's text - so you must find out which of that dictionary's items represent that.

Answer (score 0):

As a maintainer of PyMuPDF I just ***have*** to demonstrate how this works with this library:

```py
import fitz  # import pymupdf
import re

doc = fitz.open("PDF/File.pdf")
text = " ".join([page.get_text() for page in doc])
desc = re.findall(r'...', text)
```